# Serial Communication vs Device Drivers

Tags: cpu, serial-port, linux-device-driver, microcontroller

My *understanding* is that **serial communication** is for direct CPU-to-CPU (or microcontroller-to-microcontroller) communication along a serial bus.

My *understanding* is that a **device driver** is for device-to-CPU or device-to-microcontroller communication; essentially it tells the CPU how to read/write data to certain pins for correctly communicating with the raw device.

Am I correct here, or way off base? If anything that I have said so for is not true or misunderstood, please clarify/correct me! I'm basically looking for a litmus to use to help me decide when I need to use, say, SPI or I2C or UART (serial comm) or just use a driver. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Serial communication is device to device, not CPU to CPU. (The device would be a serial interface on each side.)

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchwartz (+1) - can you be more specific by what you mean when you say *device*. Wouldn't an MCU (say, an ARM CPU and some LEDs all on the same PCB) qualify as a device? In that case, isn't it the ARM CPU on the MCU communicating with the CPU on whatever its connected to (serially)? I guess I'm not seeing the difference between *device* and *CPU*. Thanks again.

Comment: A CPU is something that does computations and makes decisions. A device is something that connects a CPU to a peripheral or some other device. A microcontroller includes both a CPU and some devices on the same chip.

Comment: Thanks again @DavidSchwartz (+1), but still not understanding when a device driver is needed, and when serial comm is more appropriate.

Comment: I think you're missing something fundamental, because this is like "When should I use a car and when should I use a hammer". A device driver is a piece of software that runs on a CPU and controls a device so that it can accomplish useful work. Serial communications is a way for one device to talk to another where bits are sent one at a time.

Comment: OK, now we're starting to get to the root of my confusion. To me, your definition of a device driver and serial communication is basically the same thing. A program running on a machine uses the `XYZ` device driver to control the `XYZ` device (perhaps something connected through a USB port). If I'm interpreting your definition correctly, those commands are sent from the machine (i.e., a laptop) to the `XYZ` device via serial communication. So does this mean that device drivers are what actually use SPI serial comm? If so, SPI comm is available to user applications, so why use device drivers?

Comment: In other words, if I can write a C application to run on my laptop, and use SPI serial comm to send/receive data and commands to the `XYZ` device, then why do I need device drivers?

Comment: The code that uses the SPI serial comm *is* a device driver.

Comment: Ahh, so is it fair to say that the device driver should expose an API for user applications, and then translate those API calls to reads/writes to the SPI port/connection?

Comment: If it's sufficiently complicated, definitely. If not, it's probably still a good idea.

Comment: Thanks again, if you want to turn that into an answer I'd be happy to give you the green check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So does this mean that device drivers are what actually use SPI serial comm? If so, SPI comm is available to user applications, so why use device drivers?

Many reasons:

You might want to write code that can use various different types of serial communications without having to change the higher-level code.

You might want to moderate access to the serial port from different applications.

The serial interface may be most efficient with interrupts and you need to handle interrupts in low-level code.

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The term "serial communication" refers to any digital communication that transfers one bit at a time. This is opposed to parallel communication, where multiple bits are transferred at a time.

Your misunderstanding of serial communication comes from confusing a particular application of serial communication with the [idea of serial communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_communication). There are actually a huge number of applications.